# ADB Commands automation

Tags: shell, youtube, adb, logcat, tcpdump

I  am trying to run the following commands in Cygwin:

For Logcat dump:

```
adb devices
adb logcat –b all –c
adb logcat -b main -b events -b radio -b system -v threadtime > logcat.txt
```

For tcp dump:

```
adb root & adb wait-for-device & adb shell chmod 755 /data/
adb shell ifconfig && adb shell tcpdump -i any -w /data/youtube_server.pcap
adb pull /data/youtube_server.pcap C:\Temp\youtube_server.pcap
```

One thing I did is opening two terminals and run both in parallel. This works perfectly fine and I get the data both for TCP dump and logcat from android. However, I would like to know that it is possible to run the whole commands in one shell script. I tried writing them in shell script but once I wrote the logcat on the top and tcp down, it runs till logcat only. When I stop it, then it starts to collect the data. Please help me